# keep getting 401 using request package

Tags: node.js, express, request, body-parser, mailchimp-api-v3.0

My code is not working, I can't figure out why and it keeps giving me a 401 meaning the API key is missing so I don't know how this is happening and I would like to figure out what my problem is on this piece of code?

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

var firstName = req.body.firstName;
var lastName = req.body.lastName;
var email = req.body.email;

var data = {
    members: [
        {
            email_address: email,
            status: "subscribed"
        }
    ]
    };

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    var options = {
    url: "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listId"
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "mkouk24  Api Key"
    },

    body: jsonData
};

request(options, function(error,response,body){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
});

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000!");
});
```

Comment: where do you pass your token?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to the documentation, I think you need to use `app.use(bodyParser.json())` in order to pass parameters in post request.

Second, you should generate an API token from MailChimp and add it here `Authorization": "mkouk24  Api Key"`

More on that on this link: https://mailchimp.com/help/about-api-keys/

Comment: Great :) 
Can you please mark this answer as correct answer so that it will rank higher for others who have the same issue?